# Handling multiple AVAudioPlayers

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

I have an AVAudioPlayer for playing background music in an app (let's call it backgroundMusicPlayer), and some more players for system sounds. 
In `- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *)player` I want to reload my backgroundMusicPlayer with a new track. The question is how can I exactly define the player I need from others? Is it the `*player` pointer I need to operate with?

P.S
I'm a novice in iOS programming and would be very grateful for any kind of advice

Answer (score 0):

Yes, delegate method provide access for object which is currently 'active'. In other words, if you have 2 AVAudioPlayer `ap1` and `ap2`, and for example `ap2` finished playing then in `- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *)player` variable `player` would reference to `ap2`. It's a common practice to use variable from method signature.

Comment: The main problem is that I need to handle _only_ `ap1` object. But if I initialize the active object with some sound file, it is possible that I'll do it with `ap2`. So I need to distinguish only one specific player from the others.